# .net core 2.0 deployment error to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-2.0

Tried really hard to search online about .net core 2.0 deployment to aws but found very little latest information. AWS official doc is way out of date for core 2.0.

I have an api written .net core 2.0 and when using AWS Toolkit for VS 2017 to deploy to aws, it says everything is fine and healthy but when browsed to the app I simply got: **"An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Core 4.6.00001.0 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.0.0-rtm-26452    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?"**

From AWS console, it still says all is good. What gives?

```
16/10/2017 21:44:50         Successfully launched environment: BadderRankIdentity-dev
16/10/2017 21:43:50         Environment health has been set to GREEN
16/10/2017 21:41:41         Added EC2 instance 'i-05028bac256151d66' to Auto Scaling Group 'awseb-e-iemyzku76t-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-14ZRZLNXL0YML'.
16/10/2017 21:41:41         Adding instance 'i-05028bac256151d66' to your environment.
16/10/2017 21:40:47         Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
16/10/2017 21:39:59         Created EIP: 35.176.8.210
16/10/2017 21:39:43         Created security group named: sg-37e2165f
16/10/2017 21:39:24         Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-564641501226 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
16/10/2017 21:39:23         createEnvironment is starting.
```

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable extremely helpful **developer friendly error messages** at startup by setting the `.UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")` and .CaptureStartupErrors(true) actions in your Program.cs file, as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
      .UseIISIntegration()
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
      .Build();

  host.Run();
}
```

Obviously, these settings should be removed as soon as your troubleshooting is complete so as not to expose your application to malicious attacks.

Also checking your runtime with `dotnet --version`

Another Workaround which worked for me once is that I deployed a sample .net application , then updated the new code via **Visual Studio**.

Comment: If this solved your issue you can mark this as solved and choose this as an answer